# Badge on TabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, badge

I use **UITabBarController** for iOS app. it has 3 tabs. For example tab1 (current tab), tab2 and tab3. I want put **a small red badge** on tab3 icon when click a button on tab1. Is there any way to add it?

Comment: Consider getting in the habit of familiarizing yourself with the iOS documentation. It is a fun read sometimes and can really help you out quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITabBarItems have a badgeValue property.  You can set this when your delegate method gets fired.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

You can get the TabBarItem  #3 from the tabBarController with

```
[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
```